# Plotting list of towns in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, csv

Is there a way to plot a big (700) list of towns on Google Maps. I don't have any geographic reference, just their names in a .csv file. I've tried uploading using their help pages but it just seems to do nothing and I wondered if it's looking for more attribute in the file?

Comment: do you have a State/Province for the towns?

Comment: Google Fusion Tables would be another solution. It will import a CSV table and automatically geocode place names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Get [Google Earth Pro](https://www.google.com/intl/en_in/earth/about/versions/#download-pro) -- it's free now.
2. Make sure your CSV has column headings such as City and State.
3. Use the File -> Import feature and select your CSV
4. Step through the wizard and boom you have a solution.

Comment: Great user friendly solution, still works!